# How to auth microservices in loopback

Tags: authentication, loopbackjs, microservices, loopback

Hi i would like to know if there is an example of how to authenticate between microservices in loopback, using the USER model of loopback.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the OAuth2 implementation for Loopback: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-oauth2